# jQuery, Colorbox, jQuery syntax in parameters

Tags: jquery, syntax, colorbox

I would like to do the following however it does not work. Again I'm sure it should
be simple but I cannot get it to compile.

```
$(".villa-caller").colorbox({
    innerWidth: "850px",
    innerHeight: "500px",
    inline: true,
    href: "#"+$(this).attr("rel")+"",
    onClosed:function(){colorbox_closed();}
});
```

On the **href** parameter I am using jQuery syntax to get the value of the **rel** attribute from the clicked element.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What errors do you get ? which line causes the problem ? which browser ? can you add and example to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What is the value of the rel you are retrieving?

Comment: The value I'm retrieving is villa-2, villa-3 etc

Comment: This is the error I get from firebug: a.attributes is null
[Break On This Error] b.specified?b.value:Va.test(a.nodeName...a,"\\$&")},ua={focusin:0,focusout:0};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem here is due to the scope of `this`. Try the following:

```
$(".villa-caller").each(function() {
    $(this).colorbox({
        innerWidth: "850px",
        innerHeight: "500px",
        inline: true,
        href: "#" + $(this).attr("rel") + "",
        onClosed:function(){ colorbox_closed(); }
    });
});
```

This should ensure that `this` is the `.villa-caller` element you are initialising the `colourbox` on.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem is tha you use this here because i don't think it's referencing what you think (the current object with class "`villa-caller"`

```
href: "#"+$(this).attr("rel")+"",
```

EDIT - you could do

```
$(".villa-caller").each(function() {
    var href = "#" + $(this).attr("rel");
    $(this).colorbox({
      innerWidth: "850px",
      innerHeight: "500px",
      inline: true,
      href: href ,
      onClosed: colorbox_closed()
});
```

Comment: OK. That might be the case! How can I get the value of the rel from villa-caller? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Try the following:

**Change**

```
href: "#"+$(this).attr("rel")+""
```

**To**

```
href: "#"+$(".villa-caller").attr("rel")
```